# If I would reset security token, then other developers using that account will lost connection?

Tags: apex, api, ide, security-token

We have one account in Salesforce which is used for development by 3 developers
If I would reset the security token (in order to connect with environment via IDE), then all other developers would lose the connection?
Would they need to connect again with new security token?

Answer (score 2):

Developers using an IDE, such as VS Code/SFDX, typically authenticate with OAuth. Sessions that are created this way will persist until they are logged out, expire because of inactive use, cancelled by an administrator, the org is deleted, or is expired because there are more than five active sessions for a Connected App.

The session will remain active even if the user resets the security token, changes the password, changes the user name, becomes frozen, is outside the login times or IP address ranges, or, I believe, even if the user is deactivated. Obviously, if the user doesn't have access for a specific reason (e.g. login times), they won't be able to use the connection during that time, but the session itself should remain active.

That said, developers should not be sharing a username and password. There exists a [Free Limited Access License](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/dev_hub_license.htm) that you can obtain so that each developer can have their own username and password. This prevents problems like resetting security tokens, password changes, excessive query use, etc from affecting the other developers. You should consider getting this, as multiple users sharing a login is also a violation of Terms of Service and the Master Service Agreement.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, once reset, every user of that token needs to update it. Btw some IDE allows OAuth which is not dependent on token.

Comment: If security token is in use, then can I use just OAuth without resetting / knowing current security token?

Comment: Huh, good question and sadly I do not have an answer for that. From my experience, it should not reset the token.

Comment: OAuth does not use the security token at all.

Comment: So it can be that for the same account one user could use OAuth and other users could use security token?